# Nose2 fails to import modules, but only when run in docker

Tags: python, unit-testing, docker, celery

I have a python Celery project of the following structure:

```
├── celeryconfig.py
├── Dockerfile
│   └── _templates
├── framework
│   ├── celery
│   │   ├── celery.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── tasks
│   │   ├── tasks.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── utilities
│   │   ├── utilities.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test_celery.py
```

Which I run from the top level directory using the command `celery framework.celery.celery worker`

I have tets in the tests directory that I run using nose2. When I run it in the directory the tests pass without issue. However when the tests are run as part of a docker build process, the nose2 process fails because it can't make sense of the imports, for example

```
# test_celery.py

from framework.tasks.tasks import my_function

def test_my_function():
    # Do some testing.
```

The import of the function succeeds, but fails on the imports of the imported file, which look like:

```
# tasks.py

from framework.utilities.utilities import some_other_function
```

Part of the issue I'm having is that Celery is particular about how it itself is structured, so attempts to restructure the directory have just resulted in celery not being able to start. I'm not quite sure why the tests only fail in a docker build, which looks like this:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:198.0.0-alpline
COPY . /project
WORKDIR /project
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 python3-dev && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN nose2
```